# How to add data validation in function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, validation

I'm writing a JavaScript like this:

```
var $ = function (id) {
  return document.getElementById(id); 
}

var calculate_click = function () {
  var subtotal = parseFloat( $("subtotal").value );
  var taxRate  = parseFloat( $("tax_rate").value );

  var salesTax = subtotal * taxRate/100;
  var total= subtotal + salesTax;

  document.getElementById("sales_tax").value = salesTax;
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}

var clear_click = function () {

}

window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = calculate_click
}
```

1. Could you help me add a data validation to this application? The subtotal entry should be a valid, positive number that’s less than 30,000. The tax rate should be a valid, positive number that is less than 15. The following error messages should be displayed in the alert window when errors occur "Must be a positive number less than $30,000, Must be a positive number less than 15"
2. Could you help me add a code that enables the clear button work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: plase share your html code

Comment: Google out something. Try and then let's see where you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var calculate_click = function () {
  var subtotal = parseFloat( $("#subtotal").val() );
  var taxRate  = parseFloat( $("#tax_rate").val() );
  
  if(validateValues(subtotal, taxRate)){
    return;
  }
  
  var salesTax = subtotal * taxRate/100;
  var total= subtotal + salesTax;
  
  document.getElementById("sales_tax").value = salesTax;
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}

function validateValues(subtotal, taxRate){
   var itsBAD = false;
   
   if(subtotal<0 || subtotal>30000){
      alert("WARNING: subtotal must be possitive and less than 30.000, please re-write.");
      $("#subtotal").css("border","1px solid red");
      itsBAD = true;
  }else{
      $("#subtotal").css("border","1px solid black");
  }
  
  if((taxRate<0 || taxRate>15)){
      alert("WARNING: tax rate must be possitive and less than 15, please re-write.");
      $("#tax_rate").css("border","1px solid red");
      itsBAD = true;
  }else{
      $("#tax_rate").css("border","1px solid black");
  }
   return itsBAD;
}

function clearValues(){
   $("#sales_tax").val("");
   $("#total").val("");
   $("#subtotal").val("0");
   $("#tax_rate").val("0");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Subtotal:
    <input type="number" id="subtotal" value="0" />
    Tax rate:
    <input type="number" id="tax_rate" value="0" />
    </br>
    <input type="button" id="calculate" onClick = "calculate_click();" value="Calculate" />
    <input type="button" id="clear" onClick = "clearValues();" value="Clear" />
    </br>
    </br>
    
    Sales Tax:
    <input type="number" id="sales_tax" />
    Total:
    <input type="number" id="total" />
  </body>
</html>
```

i make this code with jQuery library, it's not the perfect solution but, this code works perfectly.